# Azure Devops: issue cloning terraform modules from another repo

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

One of the steps in our pipeline is to download modules for terraform from another repo.

It started failing intermittently, but for the last 5/6 hours has been failing solidly. This is the output we get.

```
Error: Failed to download module Could not download module "resource_group" (main.tf:1) source code from "git::https://company.visualstudio.com/Infrastructure/_git/TF-Modules": error downloading 'https://company.visualstudio.com/Infrastructure/_git/TF-Modules': E:\INFPRD01BLD02-A\externals\git\cmd\git.exe exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform\modules\resource_group'... fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ado:actual_systoken_here@company.visualstudio.com/Infrastructure/_git/TF-Modules/'
```

We havent seen this before and have no idea where to start.
I have checked that the module is there, it is. the system token is declared in the step that rewrutes the git url globally at the start of the deployment. Adding it to each step makes no difference.

Comment: There are similar errors discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21107) to see if this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we found that the powershell steps we have within the pipeline to rewrite the url in global config was failing. We have two, one to write the url into the gitconfig file and one to remove it at the end of the run.

The step to remove was failing (we need to remove it as it contains the system token) which means that the url was in the file multiple times.

This was enough for the login step to fail with the error above.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.